# Не работает (не кликается) тег select в firefox

Tags: wordpress, html5, firefox

Имеется обычный список select, не кастомизированный, например

```html
<select>
  <option value="option1">Опция 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Опция 2</option>
 </select>
```

И он не работает только в связке firefox и wordpress.
Я уже пробовал отключать все стили и скрипты, и все равно та же история.
Кто нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой?

Comment: Что значит не работает? У wp нет проблем с select'ами

Comment: Ищите ошибку в html-разметке. Возможно, ваш селект просто перекрывается другими элементами страницы

Comment: WP тут ни при чём.

Comment: Тебя пофамильный список интересует?